# How to use <Xsl: apply-templates match="othertemplate" > inside another template <xsl:template match="sometemplate">

Tags: xslt

[Curent output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34ckz.jpg) [Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Ous.jpg) I am trying to populate a dropdown list using a xsl template inside another xsl template match. I get empty dropdown. How to get the values in the dropdwon from a xsl template ?

I have 2 templates. Template 1 has a list of preferences and template 2 has list of user details. I am trying to populate a table with list of user details. And i need to populate the preference list as once of the column in table as drop down values.  I am getting an empty dropdown list. attached image for reference

XML inputs

```
<USERLIST>
    <record num="0"><SERIALNUMER>01</SERIALNUMER><NAME>Rahul</NAME> 
  <SELECTEDPREFERENCE>Pref2</SELECTEDPREFERENCE></record>
    <record num="1"><SERIALNUMER>02</SERIALNUMER><NAME>Khan</NAME> 
  <SELECTEDPREFERENCE>Pref4</SELECTEDPREFERENCE></record>
    <record num="2"><SERIALNUMER>03</SERIALNUMER><NAME>Raju</NAME> 
  <SELECTEDPREFERENCE>Pref2</SELECTEDPREFERENCE></record>
    </USERLIST>

    <PREFERENCE_LIST>
    <record num="0"><PREFERENCE_ID>pref1</PREFERENCE_ID></record>
    <record num="1"><PREFERENCE_ID>pref2</PREFERENCE_ID></record>
    <record num="2"><PREFERENCE_ID>pref3</PREFERENCE_ID></record>
    <record num="3"><PREFERENCE_ID>pref4</PREFERENCE_ID></record>
    <record num="4"><PREFERENCE_ID>pref5</PREFERENCE_ID></record>
    </PREFERENCE_LIST>
```

XSLT

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" />
    <xsl:template match="/page">
            <div style="margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff;">          
            <form action="Useraction" method="post" id="user_search" onsubmit="if (document.getElementById('user_search').action.value=='') return false; else return true;" style="margin: 0px; border: 0px; padding-top: 0px;">

                    <hr style="color: #003399; width: 100%; height: 3px; border: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px;" />
                    <table style="width: 100%; text-align: center; border: 0; background-color: #ffffff; margin-bottom: 1px; margin-top: 1px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tableheader3" style="white-space: nowrap; width: 30px;height:30px">
                                <p align="center">
                                    <input class="tabletext" type="button" value="Alle" onclick="javascript:markAll(document.getElementById('user_search'), 'UserId_')" style="width: 50px;" />
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="tableheader5" style="width: 30px; text-align: center;">Serial Number</td>
                            <td class="tableheader5" style="white-space: nowrap; width: 60px;">Name</td>
                            <td class="tableheader5" style="white-space: nowrap; width: 40px;">Preference</td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="12">
                                <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #1A15B7; background: transparent;"> </hr>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:if test="USERLIST/record">

                        <xsl:apply-templates select="USERLIST/record" />
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="12">
                                <img src="images/td_background4.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 5px; border: 0px;" alt="" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        </xsl:if>
                    </table>


            </form>
        </div>  

    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="PREFERENCE_LIST/record">
        <xsl:if test="PREFERENCE_ID=/page/parameters/preference">
            <option value="{PREFERENCE_ID }" selected="selected ">
                <xsl:value-of select="PREFERENCE_ID " />
            </option>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(PREFERENCE_ID =/page/parameters/preference)">
            <option value="{PREFERENCE_ID }">
                <xsl:value-of select="PREFERENCE_ID " />
            </option>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="USERLIST/record">
    <tr>
     <td class="tabletext" style="white-space: nowrap;">
      <xsl:value-of select="SERIALNUMER" />
     </td>
     <td class="tabletext" style="white-space: nowrap;">
      <xsl:value-of select="NAME" />
     </td>
     <td class="tabletext" style="white-space: nowrap;">
      <select class="tabletext" name="preference" style="width:79px;"> 
        <option><xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="SELECTEDPREFERENCE"/> 
        </xsl:attribute></option>
      <option value="" />
          <xsl:apply-templates name="PREFERENCE_LIST/record" />
       </select> 
     </td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `<xsl:apply-templates name="PREFERENCE_LIST/record"/>`. The  `xsl:apply-templates` instruction does not have a `name` attribute.  You can use either `<xsl:apply-templates select="some/node/s"/>` or `<xsl:call-template name="some-template"/>`.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. It is  "<xsl:apply-templates select=".  I tried both <xsl:apply-templates select= & "<xsl:call-template name=". Both did'nt work

Comment: "Didn't work" is not a good description of a problem. Post a [mcve], including input and expected output (as code, not as picture).

Comment: Added the input XML & the XSLT as suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `name` is not a valid attribute on `xsl:apply-templates`, but assuming you changed it to `select` the reason it did not select anything is that you are currently in a template matching a `record` element, and so doing `<xsl:apply-templates select="PREFERENCE_LIST/record" />` will look for a child element of `record` called `PREFERENCE_LIST`, which does not exist.

You need to navigate back up two levels in the hierarchy to get the `PREFERENCE_LIST`, so you should actually be writing this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="../../PREFERENCE_LIST/record" />
```

I am going to hazard a guess that you want the user's `SELECTEDPREFERENCE` selected as an option in the drop-down list? In this case, you need to pass the user's selected preference to the `record` template.

Try this two templates instead

```
<xsl:template match="PREFERENCE_LIST/record">
  <xsl:param name="pref" />
  <option value="{PREFERENCE_ID}">
    <xsl:if test="$pref = PREFERENCE_ID">
      <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="PREFERENCE_ID " />
  </option>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="USERLIST/record">
  <tr>
    <td class="tabletext" style="white-space: nowrap;">
      <xsl:value-of select="SERIALNUMER" />
    </td>
    <td class="tabletext" style="white-space: nowrap;">
      <xsl:value-of select="NAME" />
    </td>
    <td class="tabletext" style="white-space: nowrap;">
      <select class="tabletext" name="preference" style="width:79px;"> 
        <option value="" />
        <xsl:variable name="selectPref" select="translate(SELECTEDPREFERENCE, 'P', 'p')" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../../PREFERENCE_LIST/record">
          <xsl:with-param name="pref" select="$selectPref" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </select> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the use of `translate` was simply because the check would be case-sensitive, and so `Pref2` would not match `pref2`.

See it in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7mS

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tim C . Yes the issue was with accessing the right node from root path. Moving the hierarchy is the key  "../../". Also populating the pre-selected value worked great.